# A library wants me to use the await operator on method that they didn't mark as async. Visual Studio complains. Am I missing something?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Windows application, written in C#, for a company. I was to use the Google Cloud Firestore package, and have installed it into the project in Visual Studio. I started to write some code to test the library when I came across an issue.

A method from the library, with a return type of `Task`, is not marked with the `async` modifier. The library's own documentation says to use the `await` operator with this method, but Visual Studio tells me I can't do that, as it isn't marked as `async`.

Looking at the source code for the package, it appears the method just points to an internal method, of the same name, which *is* marked as `async`. I assume this `async` marking doesn't extend to public method that calls it. Is this a mistake on the part of the developers of the package, or am I missing something? I'm fairly new to C# but I have been coding for a while.

Comment: What is the method name, what is the namespace or documentation so we can check for our selves. If you cant use await, most likely your calling method isnt async

Comment: It's specifically the GetSnapshotAsync() method in the Query class. The source is here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Query.cs#L600.

And this user guide shows several examples of using await on this method: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/userguide.html

Comment: I just noticed Visual Studio says "(awaitable)" next to the method information when I hover over it. I'm looking into that to see what it means.

Comment: You will likely need to mark your calling method as async `public async Task MyCallingMethod() { await GetSnapshotAsync()`

Comment: Ohhhh yeah that makes sense. I've made this mistake before when doing Node.js development. I just tried that and it fixed it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Remember, there is no such thing as code in a library being "marked as async".  `async` is just a keyword that is in *your source code* that puts the *compiler* into a mode where it recognizes the keyword `await` and generates an asynchronous workflow. VS is telling you that **YOUR** code is not marked as asynchronous, not the *library* code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely need to mark your calling method as `async`

```
public async Task MyCallingMethod() 
{ 
    ...
    await GetSnapshotAsync();
```

---

**Further Reading**

[await operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

> You can use the await operator **only in a method, lambda expression, or
>   anonymous method that is modified by the async keyword**.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you return a Task, your method doesn't have to be async. It's the implementation of the await operator that requires your method is async.

```cs
   public Task DontAwait(){
      log("waiting");
      return Task.Delay(100);
   }

   public async Task Await(){
      log("waiting");
      await Task.Delay(100);
      log("finished waiting");
   }
```

Comment: Although this is correct, just a note to future readers. this is actually not the same thing as using `async` and *awaiting* a call. The subtle difference comes about when an there is an *exception* and the method is not just trivially forwarding the task to the result. When you use the `async` keyword, any *exceptions* that occur are placed on the task via the compiler generated `IAsyncStateMachine` Implementation , to achieve the same behavior, a `try catch` would be needed and the exceptions passed to `Task.FromException`.